# Entity Framework can't blend (by joining or otherwise) Tables with Views in complex data-types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have a programmer telling me that "Entity Framework can't blend (by joining or otherwise) Tables with Views in complex data-types" Is this true?

Basically he's trying to pull some data from a normal table along with a piece of information from a scalar function on MS SQL. He couldn't get that to work, so I threw the information into a view, and he says he can't use views.

I'm at a loss... If it's true ok, if it's not can someone point me to an article explaining how to handle views in Entity Framework? Appreciate any information.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Based on the information you've provided, your development resource is mistaken. You can Google, "Use Views with Entity Framework" and fine plenty of guides.